# Display image from live webcam as taken, with four different color filters and in B/W

Tags: python, opencv

I have a live webcam windows which means there are six subdivided windows in a single window live. And show pictures in colored and black and white. Is there anyway I can make the code minimalistically minimized? I believe the code is considerably long.

```
import cv2
import cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def threshold_slow(T, image):
    # grab the image dimensions
    h = image.shape[0]
    w = image.shape[1]
    d = image.shape[2]
    # loop over the image, pixel by pixel
    for y in range(0, h):
        for x in range(0, w):
            for z in range(0, d):
                # threshold the pixel

                if image[y, x,z] >= T:
                    image[y, x,z] = 255
                else:
                    image[y, x,z] = 0

    # return the thresholded image
    return image
def grab_frame(cam):





    #cv2.namedWindow("test")

    #img_counter = 0

    while True:
        ret, color1 = cam.read()
        #r = 100.0 / color1.shape[1]
        r = 640.0 / color1.shape[1]
        #r = 0.25
        dim = (100, int(color1.shape[0] * r))
        dim = (640,480)
        # perform the actual resizing of the image and show it
        color = cv2.resize(color1, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)


        #color = color1.copy()
        b = color.copy()
        # set green and red channels to 0
        b[:, :, 1] = 0
        b[:, :, 2] = 0


        g = color.copy()
        # set blue and red channels to 0
        g[:, :, 0] = 0
        g[:, :, 2] = 0

        r = color.copy()
        # set blue and green channels to 0
        r[:, :, 0] = 0
        r[:, :, 1] = 0

        #y= color.copy()
        #gray = cv2.cvtColor(l,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        #_,y = cv2.threshold(gray, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        #y = cv2.cvtColor(y, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

        y = cv2.add(r,g)

        d = color.copy()
        gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(d,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        _,p = cv2.threshold(gray1, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        p = cv2.cvtColor(p, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
        #threshold_slow(220,p)
        return [color,b,g,r,y,p]


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    #cv2.waitKey(0)
while(1):
    ret, color = cam.read()
    [color,b,g,r,y,p] = grab_frame(cam)
    horiz = np.hstack((color,b,g))
    #verti = np.vstack((color,r))
    horiz1 = np.hstack((r,y,p))
    verti = np.vstack((horiz,horiz1))
    cv2.imshow('HORIZONTAL', verti)

    if not ret:
        break
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k%256 == 27:
        # ESC pressed
        print("Escape hit, closing...")
        break


cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- First, get rid of all the unneeded whitespace. Use consistent amount between functions (Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), recommends two).
- PEP8 also recommends using spaces in lists, after the commas, and `lower_case` for all variables and functions (your `T` in `threshold_slow` violates this).
- Don't use magic numbers in your code. Give them readable names and if necessary make them global constants:

  ```
  WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480
  ```
- Next, since your images are already `numpy` arrays, use that fact. Your (unused) `threshold_slow` function can be replaced by a single line using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

  ```
  def threshold_fast(T, image):
      return np.where(image >= T, 255, 0)
  ```

  Note that this does not modify the image inplace. It is a bad practice to do that *and* return a modified/new object. You should decide, either return a new object *or* modify in place and return `None`.
- The `import cv` is not used (and I could not even find a way to install it anymore).
- Tuple assignment works also without a list on the left side, just do `color, b, g, r, y, p = grab_frame(cam)`. The same is true when returning a tuple (`return color, b, g, r, y, p`).
- Arguably, I would split up your `grab_frame` code into subfunctions like `red(image)`, `green(image)`, `blue(image)`, `yellow(image)`, `black_and_white(image)`.

  ```
  def red(image):
      """Copy only the red channel from image"""
      out = np.zeros_like(image)
      # for some reason red is in the last channel
      out[:, :, 2] = image[:, :, 2]
      return out
  ...
  ```

  While this move will not make your code shorter, it will make it more readable.
- Note that the canonical order is red, green, blue (RGB). If at all possible I would stick to that. I'm not sure why openCV would deviate from that.
- You should at least add a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to each of your functions as a rudimentary documentation. See above for a short example.
- You can use `while True` instead of `while(1)`. No parenthesis needed and `True` is unambiguous (even for those people who both know C-like languages, where `0` is `False` and shell scripting languages like bash, where non-zero is `False`).
- I would also add a `tile(images, rows)` function that puts your images into rows and columns. You could just use the [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) `grouper` for this:

  ```
  from itertools import zip_longest

  def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
      "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
      # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
      args = [iter(iterable)] * n
      return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
  ```
- Since you [seem to want to use different amounts of tiles, and different effects](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233347/pyopencv-code-that-displays-color-b-w-and-canny-images-input-from-single-live-w), it might make sense to keep a list of functions to apply to the base image, so that in the end you only need one call:

  ```
  def identity(x):
      return x

  def tile(images, cols, fillvalue=None):
      return np.vstack(np.hstack(group)
                       for group in grouper(images, cols, fillvalue))

  funcs = identity, red, black_and_white, canny
  images = (func(image) for func in funcs)
  # arrange them in a 2x2 grid
  cv2.imshow('HORIZONTAL', tile(images, cols=2, fillvalue=np.zeros_like(image)))
  ```

  If the number of images is not evenly divisible by the number of columns, the row is filled up with blank images.
- You should put your main calling code under a [`if __name__ == "__main__"` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script.